# Android: custom sound not playing in FCM push notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Be informed we are trying to send a push notification with a custom sound to user's android devices. While sending push notifications using FCM from our app, the message does arrive in user's device but the custom sound set in the payload does not play. The notification arrives,but the custom sound does not play and nor does the default notification sound play.
Here is the payload we are using

```
 $notification = [
            'title' =>"Hello",
            'body' =>"Hello",
            'image'=>''
            'sound'=>'https://mbracecloud.com/sound.mp3'
            ];
```

Firebase.java:NotificationCompat.Builder

```
Uri soundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MainActivity.asw_fcm_channel)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        Notification noti = notificationBuilder.build();
        noti.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(notification_id, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Do guide us as where we are going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In order to receive a push notification with sound push data should contain sound param,
This is an example of push data:

```
{
  "token": "client_notification_token", <- or topic
  "notification": {
    "title": "Push notification title",
    "body": "Push body",
    "sound": "filename", <-- points to src/res/raw/filename.mp3
  }
  ...
}
```

As shown in above sample, you need to save that sound file(filename.mp3) inside res > raw folder.

Now Lets come to the coding part on how to handle this sound file.
I'm doing this handling of sound in NotificationChannel object.

```
mChannel.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.waiting_ringtone)
```

I hope this helps, Upvote and Marks as answered if it is helpful